# any tool to help to match multiple lines and output per line

Tags: regex, awk

This is my input:

```
time1 start a
time2 start b
time3 start a
time4 end a
time5 end b
time6 start a
time7 end a
time8 end a
```

I would like to product the following:

```
time1 time4 a
time2 time5 b 
time3 time7 a
time6 time8 a
```

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? How can you define the logic to do it?

Comment: sed is for 1 line. As soon as you say "multiple lines", sed is NOT the right tool.

Comment: No wonder I am going nowhere.  Is there any tool that I can use to help?  Of course I can always resort to writing codes.

Comment: sed is an excellent choice for simple substitutions on a single line. It has many language constructs but the ONLY ones you should use are s, g, and p (with -n), the rest became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. awk is the standard UNIX tool for all other text manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '$2=="start"{s[$3,++sc[$3]]=$1} $2=="end"{print s[$3,++ec[$3]],$1,$3}' file
time1 time4 a
time2 time5 b
time3 time7 a
time6 time8 a
```